# Having an issue running Maps app on flutter-API key not found

Tags: google-maps, flutter

**So I'm having an issue figuring out the solution for this issue.

I'm trying to run a simple map app and all I can see is a blank screen.

After spending several hours online trying to find similar post I couldn't manage to fix it.

### Map SDK enabled for android as well as for IOS.

### [Maps_Enabled_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3WrE.jpg)

this is the manifest part**

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="integrativeUI2020"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">



        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
          <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyDkKQaxxxxlIhmp1nmQrVQHnE"/>
```

**the code is**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**For some uncleared reason I see in the console this error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: you shouldn't post your api key online. make sure to invalidate this one and create a new one.
Maybe there

Comment: @Saskia if you look closely you will see a bunch of "xxxx" I ruined the string

Comment: put the meta-data outside of the Activity. it should be inside your Application.